# How to add a caption with continuing numbering when using the Insert Box command in latex?

Tags: latex

I have used the `InsertBoxL` command in Latex to have 3 consecutive images, one below the other, with text beside each image. Is there a way to insert a caption with continuous numbering within Latex using the command above?

The Latex I have used so far is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

 \InsertBoxL{0}{\rule{1.6in}{0.9in}} %text inserted here 
 \bigskip
 \InsertBoxL{0}{\rule{1.6in}{0.9in}} %text inserted here
 \bigskip
 \InsertBoxL{0}{\rule{1.6in}{0.9in}} %text inserted here

\end{document}
```

I have replaced my actual images with the `\rule` command.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you can use the `\captionof` macro from the caption package

Comment: From which package is your `InsertBoxL` macro? The code you show does not compile ...

Comment: Edited @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz !

Answer (score 1):

To add captions to your boxes, you could use the `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

 \InsertBoxL{0}{\rule{1.6in}{0.9in}} \captionof{figure}{some text}
 \bigskip
 \InsertBoxL{0}{\rule{1.6in}{0.9in}} \captionof{figure}{some text}
 \bigskip
 \InsertBoxL{0}{\rule{1.6in}{0.9in}} \captionof{figure}{some text}

\end{document}
```

However instead of these strange box thingies, minipages might be easier:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{1.6in}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1.6in}
\captionof{figure}{some text}
\end{minipage}%

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{1.6in}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.6in}
\captionof{figure}{some tefffffxt}
\end{minipage}%

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{1.6in}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.6in}
\captionof{figure}{some text}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are also ready-to-use packages for captions besides images:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{heading}
\end{SCfigure}
\begin{SCfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{heading}
\end{SCfigure}
\begin{SCfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{heading}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to place the caption below the box/image?

Comment: If you want the caption below the image, use a normal `figure` instead of this strange box thingy?

Comment: I wanted 3 images, one below one another with text beside each image.